# Is there a simplistic way of describing the proof to the undecidability of David Hilbert's 10th problem?

Tags: computability, sets, number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equation

I recently have been reading a bunch about David Hilbert's famous 10th problem, and trying to understand its proof. I am currently in the process of reading through an explanation of the proof, given by one of the people involved in trying to solve the problem, Martin Davis, Ph. D. It is really well explained, but pretty long.

Therefore I wonder, is there an easy/short way to explain the proof, albeit by simplifying some of its points, and skipping proving some minor components of the general proof?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question in the title is subjective, but I suspect no. Hilbert's 10th is one of the most important, but also one of the most complex, results of the last century. The proof itself spans 21 years of research by 4 mathematicians. If the majority of the proof isn't "easy" from Davis's text, I don't know if we can hope for something simpler.

However, there are good expositions of the structure of the proof. It has now been fully formalized (as of 2019), which would be one place to investigate to understand the proof's components. You may find the following paper useful:

- *Hilbert’s Tenth Problem in Coq.* Dominique Larchey-Wendling and Yannick Forster. FSCD 2019. [Link](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/Publications/documents/Larchey-WendlingForster_2019_H10_in_Coq.pdf)

The introduction to the paper gives a nice overview of the history of the proof, and the structure that was chosen for the formalization effort. An excerpt: the authors show that
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Halt}
  &\preccurlyeq \mathsf{PCP} \preccurlyeq \mathsf{MM} \preccurlyeq \mathsf{FRACTRAN} \\
  &\preccurlyeq \mathsf{DIO}_{\mathsf{FORM}} \preccurlyeq \mathsf{DIO}_{\mathsf{ELEM}} \preccurlyeq \mathsf{DIO}_{\mathsf{SINGLE}} \preccurlyeq \mathsf{H10}
\end{align*}

So understanding the proof is just a matter of understanding each of the 7 reductions above.